# I found no \citation commands---while reading file

Tags: bibliographies

I am trying to cite all the articles in the citations.bib such like that:

```
\documentclass[margin,line,11pt]{res}
\begin{document}
\begin{resume}
...
\section{\sc Selected Publications}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{citations}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{resume}

\end{document}
```

But I got three errors by running BibTex uisng TexShop:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2013)
The top-level auxiliary file: Resume_PlantGenetics.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file Resume_PlantGenetics.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Resume_PlantGenetics.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Resume_PlantGenetics.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

What's wrong of my tex file? Thanks in advance.

Here is the citations.bib (just directly exported from google scholar):

```
@article{cai2008quantitative,
  title={Quantitative trait loci for aluminum resistance in Chinese wheat landrace FSW},
  author={Cai, Shibin and Bai, Gui-Hua and Zhang, Dadong},
  journal={Theoretical and Applied Genetics},
  volume={117},
  number={1},
  pages={49--56},
  year={2008},
  publisher={Springer}
}
...
@article{song2006potato,
  title={Potato Virus Determined by the Improved DAS-ELISA Technique},
  author={SONG, Ji-xuan and FAN, Shi-jie and DONG, Ying-ping and YAN, Qian and ZHANG, Min and ZHANG, De-yu},
  journal={Guizhou Agricultural Sciences},
  volume={5},
  pages={028},
  year={2006}
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest switching to `moderncv`

Comment: @DadongZhang The suggested duplicate uses `biblatex`, but it's the same problem.